# Set windows phone store application start up page instead of MainPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development, I have MainPage.xaml which is start up page by Default, I have used this page as a login page, But every time I run my application it opens login page and need to put username and password, Instead of MainPage I want to set UserList.xanl as my start up page.
the next event is MainPage.xaml page_loaded event,

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/UserList.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

I dont want to use above code,
I have googled around but there was not any clue? Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200692/windows-phone-8-1-check-if-password-set-else-load-new-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing it in your `WMAppManifest`?

Reference: [Setting The Start Page in Windows Phone 7 Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/setting-the-start-page-in-windows-phone-7-application/)

Comment: It works,change the Navigation Page in WMAppManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can change startup page in the app.xaml.cs file.

Find this method:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
```

and change `MainPage` to `UserList` here:

```
if ( !rootFrame.Navigate( typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments ) )
```

Comment: can't find this method in app.xaml.cs